Problems with Tweepy (Python)
I'm studying data mining and systems automation. I'm having trouble with the second message when trying to run the code:
"tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
Your client app is not configured with the appropriate oauth1 app permissions for this endpoint."
Is there any way around this? Are there other libraries that can help me?
Is there any way around this? Are there other libraries that can help me?

"I'm studying data mining..." You'll need a paid for access tier for the X API to fetch any data. The "Free" access tier can just post tweets and not much else.

That means you don't have permission to use that API. You should check your API settings and permissions. Alternatively, you can use other Python libraries like Twarc, TwitterAPI, or Python-Twitter. You can install them using pip:
pip install twarc
pip install TwitterAPI
pip install python-twitter

